# return enum of impl in rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to export a value from a field of a structure, this field is an enum to avoid typing errors and it throws me an error where I cannot return it and I really don't know what I can do.

I cannot move out of `self.package` which is behind a shared reference
move occurs because `self.package` has type `issues::PackageManager`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait.

```
pub enum PackageManager {
    NPM,
    PNPM,
    YARN,
}

pub struct ProjectStruct {
    name: String,
    description: String,
    version: u8,
    package: PackageManager,
}

pub trait Project {
    fn new(name: String, description: String) -> Self;

    fn set_version(&mut self, version: u8);
    fn get_version(&self) -> u8;

    fn set_name(&mut self, name: String);
    fn get_name(&self) -> String;

    fn set_package_manager(&mut self, package_manager: PackageManager);
    fn get_package_manager(&self) -> PackageManager;
}

impl Project for ProjectStruct {
    fn new(name: String, description: String) -> Self {
        ProjectStruct {
            name,
            description,
            version: 1,
            package: PackageManager::PNPM,
        }
    }

    fn set_version(&mut self, version: u8) {
        self.version = version
    }

    fn get_version(&self) -> u8 {
        self.version
    }

    fn set_name(&mut self, name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    fn get_name(&self) -> String {
        self.name.clone()
    }

    fn set_package_manager(&mut self, package_manager: PackageManager) {
        self.package = package_manager
    }

    fn get_package_manager(&self) -> PackageManager {
        /* * no error
        match self.package {
            PackageManager::NPM => PackageManager::NPM,
            PackageManager::PNPM => PackageManager::PNPM,
            PackageManager::YARN => PackageManager::YARN,
        }*/

        // error
        self.package

        /* *cannot move out of `self.package` which is behind a shared reference
        move occurs because `self.package` has type `issues::PackageManager`, which does not implement the `Copy` traitrustc */
    }
}
```

I am trying to return the value of the field without switch since it can contain multiple options.

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cb1162d93339513d57dbbe9896517fb1).

Comment: They meant that they have to do the `match` instead of just returning `self.package`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman you forgot to uncomment the line `self.package` to reproduce the error.

Comment: If I didn't know how to place it... if it produced the error, now that I think about it, it's more logical, I'll edit it, thanks

Comment: vscode detected the error and did not let me build

Answer (score 6):

The error "does not implement the `Copy` trait" is pointing you in the right direction. All you need to do is implement `Copy` for that type, which you can do with a simple derive.

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy)] // Copy requires Clone
pub enum PackageManager {
    NPM,
    PNPM,
    YARN,
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4d5aaf09095a6e86492834c9e129dc53)

Comment: Adding others like `Debug`, `Eq` and `PartialEq` can be a good habit to get into if you ever need to compare these or dump them out for debugging/display.

Comment: Great, I really appreciate the answer, because I'm new and I'm learning!